# Pokemon Bank Pokedex Data

Tags: pokemon-bank

If I restart Pokemon Moon, will I lose all my Pokedex Entries in Pokemon bank? I have like 792 out of 800 Pokemon Seen and Caught in the Pokedex in Pokemon Bank, but if I restart Pokemon Moon, will those entries disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries in your bank won't dissapear. Your Pokemon Games and the Bank are 2 different things. What's in the bank will stay there unless it's reset/deleted from the bank. I think that for now the only way to do this would be to not renew your subcription for 6 months after it ends so Nintendo will delete every data about your bank. (Don't ever let this happen if you have pokemons in there).

For your in-game pokedex if you want your entries back you'll have to move manually all the pokemons you have in your bank back in your game at least once.

Comment: Really? Moving Pokémon from Bank to Moon will make Pokèdex entries appear in Bank?

Comment: Oh my bad I didnt read the question right ^^' I thought he meant the pokedex entries in his game. The entries in your bank won't dissapear. Your Pokemon Games and the Bank are 2 different things. What's in the bank will stay there unless it's reset/deleted from the bank. I think that for now the only way to do this would be to not renew your subcription for 6 months after it ends so Nintendo will delete every data about your bank. (Don't ever let this happen if you have pokemons in there). Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the Pokédex of the Bank will not dissapear even if you don't renew the subscription. I've tried it and waited for 1 year, bought the subscription again and everything was there, even the data of the cartridges I used, it only erases the Pokémon, not all the other info.